# How to use Pgfplot to draw vertical lines with use of data taken from file

Tags: pgfplots, plot

I have one-column example.csv file with time samples (with different intervals).
My question is how to use Pgfplot to generate plot with several vertical lines in time samples taken from .csv file such as:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Krzysiek

Answer (score 5):

You can use `ycomb`s and make up a value to draw the verticals.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymax=2,ymin=0]
\addplot+[ycomb,dashdotted,thick,no marks] table[x=x,y expr=2] {
x
1
5
12
34
68
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @percusse for you quick response. How to change your code if I have data not in the code as ({
x
1
5
12
34
68
};) but in the .csv file?

Comment: @krzybrzo use something like `\addplot[ycomb,densely dashed] plot table[x index=10,y expr={2}]
{timedata.cvs};` (if the data to be plotted is in column 11 of your `timedata.cvs` file) or `\addplot[ycomb,densely dashed] plot table[x={time},y expr={2}]
{timedata.cvs};` if the column to be plotted has the header "time" in your `.cvs` file.

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina thank you for response. All is almost clear. I have one more question: proposed above code draw line from coordinate y equals 0 to y equals 2. How can I draw line for example from y equals -2 to y equals 2?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when you have more options in your \begin{axis}[ymax=2,ymin=0] line with horizontal lines rather than vertical. I tried the following which worked standalone but not in another plot.

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmax=2,xmin=0]
\addplot+[xcomb,dashdotted,thick,no marks] table[x expr=2,y=y] {
y
1
5
12
34
68
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}